# Is the Axiom of Extensionality required to prove the Axiom of Existence from the Weak Axiom of Existence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm going through the first chapter in Hrbaek and Jech's Introduction to Set Theory, and got confused by the very second exercise in the chapter.

The question asks the reader to show that one can deduce the Axiom of Existence from the Weak Axiom of Existence together with the Axiom Schema of Comprehension. And as a hint, the book suggests the reader to consider the set $\{ x\in A \mid x \neq x \}$.

However, I feel that this is problematic since it would require the Axiom of Extensionality to lead a contradiction from $x\neq x$.

To avoid the unnecessary inclusion of Extensionality, I figured that the set $\{ x \in A \mid x \notin A \}$ might do the job, but am unsure if there isn't any underlying mistakes.

So my question is, is there a way one can show that $\{ x\in A \mid x \neq x \}$ is empty without using Extensionality? Also, is considering $\{ x \in A \mid x \notin A \}$ 'mistake-free' in the sense that it is logically sound to use such a set to answer the question?

---

*Just to clarify, these are the definitions of the axioms that the book uses:

**Axiom of Existence** There exists a set with no elements.

**Axiom of Extensionality** If every element of $X$ is an element of $Y$, and every element of $Y$ is an element of $X$, then $X=Y$.

**Axiom Schema of Comprehension** Let $P(x)$ be a property of $x$. For any set $A$, there is a set $B$ such that $x \in B$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $P(x)$.

**Weak Axiom of Existence** There exists some set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrbaček and Jech, as they explain in that chapter (in my 2nd edition it's under the heading "Properties") use first order logic (so $\forall, \exists$ plus connectors like $\lor,\land,\lnot$ etc) along with identity ($=$) to define properties, and they name the axioms of identity, among which $\forall x: x=x$. These are just given **logical** facts, not yet set theory facts.

The axiom of extensionality states that we can conclude identity $x=y$ from $(\forall z: z \in x \to z \in y) \land (\forall z: z \in y \to z \in x)$ and this makes the connection between $=$ and the domain of sets (which has $\in$ as primitive symbol).

In particular, $x \neq x$ (which is just shorthand for $\lnot(x=x)$ in logic with identity) is false for all $x$ (it's a contradiction of an axiom for $=$ in logic) and that's why if $A$ is any set then $\{x \in A: x \neq x\}$ is indeed $\emptyset$, showing that the axioms of weak existence and comprehension together imply existence (of the empty set).

It's subtle.